# make calls ring (sound) while notifications vibrate only

Tags: notifications, audio, ringtone, vibration

Is it possible to control volume in such a way that I can make ringtone ring (sound), while notifications only vibrate.  It doesn't matter if calls vibrate or not, ideally though it does vibrate.  I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4, running on Android 5.0.1.

I have seperate sound channels for Ringtone & Notifications to control.  If I set Ringtone to full, and Notifications to 'Off' (leftmost), the ringtone will sound, while notifications will not sound at all and not even vibrate. If I set the sound setting to 'Vibrate', both ringtone and notifications will vibrate, but the ringtone will not sound.

Can this be solved, natively or using a third-party app?